# How to Xfail multi-parametrised test definitions in py.test?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

if anyone knows how do deal with the following issue:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("paramA, paramB", params_variable)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("bool", (True, False))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("size", sizes_variable)
def test_definition(paramA, paramB, boolA, boolB, size):
    assert something
```

Lets imagine that tests results can be like this:

> FAILED test_definition[paramA_1-paramB_2-bool_true-size_4] -
> AssertionError: assert False
>
> FAILED test_definition[paramA_4-paramB_6-bool_false-size_1] -
> AssertionError: assert False

How to wrap a specific constellation of parameters to marked them as Xfail?
Is it possible?

When I put xfail to some specific parameters, I will marked all Test Cases with this parameter as Xfail - but I only want to mark specific constellation (in the case above - only two cases from a lot of)

billion points for someone who will resolve this problem

Answer (score 2):

If you know the parameter combinations where you want to have the `xfail` marker, you can add the marker in `pytest_collection_modifyitems` based on the function name:

**conftest.py**

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        if item.name in ("test_definition[paramA_1-paramB_2-bool_true-size_4]",
                         "test_definition[paramA_4-paramB_6-bool_false-size_1]"):
            item.add_marker("xfail")
```

This has to be done in the `conftest.py` in the same directory as the test, or in a directory above.

Comment: Yeah, you won 1000points. This works perfectly, thanks!